# How to know whether the navigation is cancelled or not?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am navigating to a route but one of the route guard is returning false in Angular 13.
how to know whether navigation is done or cancelled.
I have done below but then block and finally block consoles are printing even the route guard returns false.

```
this.router.navigate(['/user/admin/editor'])
      .then(() =>{
        console.log('then block');
        
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('catch block');
        
      })
      .finally(() => {
        console.log('final block');
        
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to [the router events](https://angular.io/api/router/Event), more specifically, to the [NavigationCancel](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationCancel) event:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(e => e instanceof NavigationCancel)
).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('navigation was cancelled');
})
```

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: because it will execute when i routing from all pages

Comment: You can put another filter. The event variable `e` actually contains the `url`. You can have something like `filter(e => e instanceof NavigationCancel && e.url.includes("yourRoute"))`,

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to give you possible way to do your work

you can use filter to the `event` variable instance it's contains `url`.

```
this.router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationCancel && e.url.includes("Your Routes"))
```